# When creating a user file upload button how can I choose the folder in which I want the file to be uploaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="fileupload">
        <button class="button">+</button>
        <input type="file" name="myfile" id="filebutton"
        accept="image/png" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
      </div>
```

What attribute should I add in my code in order to choose where the file uploaded by the user is saved in the code folder.

Comment: Why not simply add a `<select>` with names of possible folders, then pass that name to the server in addition to the file?

Answer (score 1):

Following [this tutorial](https://html.form.guide/php-form/html5-input-type-file.html), using PHP you can do this :

```
$dest=__DIR__.'/uploads/'.$upload_file_name;
```

and replace the  path by whatever you want.

(this code comes from **The complete PHP script so far** section)